# Definition of a scalar, quadratic function of a vector

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I've been studying Conjugate Gradient method. Before the method is explained, the  book starts with the definition of a scalar, quadratic function of a vector like the below.
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - b^Tx+c \quad \quad \text{where A : matrix, b: vector, c : scalar}$$
Then, the book said f(x) is minimized by the solution to $Ax=b$.

However, I don't understand why the author defines the function in the way above, and what's the meaning of the function. Is there any

Comment: It is an algebraic expression for what is usually known as energy functional.

Comment: Is there any material that I can acquire the knowledge of the quadratic function?